# How to forbid file creation in a directory on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, permissions

What folder permissions and/or attributes should I set in order to restrict files creation inside it?

I tried to unset any write permissions and set read-only attribute (using Win API), but I could still create a new file. *"C:\Program Files"* is a good example of what I want to get as a result.

BTW, I'm using Qt 4.8.

Code of the function I use for permission changing (taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
DWORD AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor (
    LPTSTR pszObjName,          // name of object
    SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,  // type of object
    LPTSTR pszTrustee,          // trustee for new ACE
    TRUSTEE_FORM TrusteeForm,   // format of trustee structure
    DWORD dwAccessRights,       // access mask for new ACE
    ACCESS_MODE AccessMode,     // type of ACE
    DWORD dwInheritance         // inheritance flags for new ACE
) 
{
    DWORD dwRes = 0;
    PACL pOldDACL = NULL, pNewDACL = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;

    if (NULL == pszObjName) 
        return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    // Get a pointer to the existing DACL.

    dwRes = GetNamedSecurityInfo(pszObjName, ObjectType, 
          DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
          NULL, NULL, &pOldDACL, NULL, &pSD);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) {
        printf( "GetNamedSecurityInfo Error %u\n", dwRes );
        goto Cleanup; 
    }  

    // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for the new ACE. 

    ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea.grfAccessPermissions = dwAccessRights;
    ea.grfAccessMode = AccessMode;
    ea.grfInheritance= dwInheritance;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TrusteeForm;
    ea.Trustee.ptstrName = pszTrustee;

    // Create a new ACL that merges the new ACE
    // into the existing DACL.

    dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, pOldDACL, &pNewDACL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)  {
        printf( "SetEntriesInAcl Error %u\n", dwRes );
        goto Cleanup; 
    }  

    // Attach the new ACL as the object's DACL.

    dwRes = SetNamedSecurityInfo(pszObjName, ObjectType, 
          DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
          NULL, NULL, pNewDACL, NULL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)  {
        printf( "SetNamedSecurityInfo Error %u\n", dwRes );
        goto Cleanup; 
    }  

    Cleanup:

        if(pSD != NULL) 
            LocalFree((HLOCAL) pSD); 
        if(pNewDACL != NULL) 
            LocalFree((HLOCAL) pNewDACL); 

        return dwRes;
}
```

Comment: This looks like C code, not C++.

Comment: @Simple, sure, though WinAPI is compatible with C

Comment: See this help : How to set, view, change, or remove special permissions for files and folders in Windows XP([https://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419/en-us)

Comment: @Isalamon, I saw this manual and found that "advanced write permissions" is similar to what I want to use, but I didn't manage to find any samples of using it in programming.

Comment: I would like to advise you to experiment first without any programming. Just open Windows Explorer, create a folder and open Properties -> Security.